# Getting Hub Context for ASPNet.Core Signal-R (.NET Core 2.1) RC

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC1.
I'm also using Signal-R for it (found here):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I'm creating a .NET Core console application that's hosting Kestrel and using Signal-R.  I've pretty much set it up *exactly* as the getting started documentation states for setting up the Startup.

This all works great.   I'm able to connect to the it, get my HTML with signal-R script in it, receive messages I crafted with Clients.All.SendAsync.   Works great.

**BUT** 
I want to be able to send a message to clients, from outside the Hub.   Where some event happens in my application, and a message is sent to clients.   In full .NET, I'd use the GlobalHost and get the context.   In **ALL** my searches on Stack Overflow, they reference something that no longer works, or used within an REST API controller that's passed in the IHubContext.

I have an event listener in my program.cs, and when the event is triggered, I'd love to be able to send a message to my UserInterfaceHub.

So -- how do I get the hub context in Program.CS - so I can send messages to it (call the SwitchUI method) from within an event delegate I have in Program.CS?

**StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  {
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded      = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy   = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder =>  {builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials();}));
    services.AddSignalR();

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseSignalR(routes => {routes.MapHub<UserInterfaceHub>("/uihub");});
    app.UseMvc();



    //app.Run(async (context) =>{await context.Response.WriteAsync("Active");});
}
```

**Program.CS**

```
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:" + appProperties.HostPort.ToString().Trim())
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .Build()
    .Start();
```

**UserInterfaceHub.cs**

```
namespace InterfaceModule.Hubs  {
    public class UserInterfaceHub : Hub  {
        public async Task SwitchUI(string message) {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveEvent", message);
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()   {
            //await SwitchUI("HOWDY NEW PERSON!");
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**edit** adding clarity.

In Program.CS, I have this event delegate:
            //now that we're ready, start listening.
            await

```
deviceClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync(ModuleProperties.InputName, OnReceiveEvent, deviceClient);
            Console.WriteLine("INIT: Event Message Input handler created: [{0}]", ModuleProperties.InputName);
```

which is this:

```
        static async Task<MessageResponse> OnReceiveEvent(Message message, object userContext)  {
//HOW DO I REACH THE HUB FROM HERE SO I CAN SEND A MESSAGE TO THE LISTENERS?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

```
 app.UseSignalR(routes => {routes.MapHub<UserInterfaceHub>("/uihub");});
```

will register your hub with the DI container.  Then to get access to it, you either use constructor injection to inject in the `IHubContext<UserInterfaceHub>` (this works for example in a Web Controller) or access it directly from the DI container by doing the following:

```
 var hub = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<UserInterfaceHub>>();
```

(for example if executed in the startup.cs `Configure` method)

If you don't have access to the `app.ApplicationServices` which is basically an `IServiceProvider` at the location you need to access the hub, then you will need to either 1) get that class to work with dependency injection to inject in the `IHubContext<UserInterfaceHub>` or `IServiceProvider` 2) Setup a static Services global var via `Configure` so that you can have access to one of them globally, or find some other way to access the DI container (aka IServiceProvider) to get your hub via the above line of code.

Once you have your hub, then sending the message to the registered clients is a simple as calling the method on your hub.

```
 await hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveEvent", message);
```

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents, there is always some controversy because of the ServiceLocator antipattern (passing the DI container through constructors). You can also pass HttpContext or IHttpContextAccessor and access your registered services through the context (HttpContext.RequestServices) which will return a IServiceProvider.

Comment: @FranciscoTena I agree that using the HttpContext.RequestServices is a great approach. It still of course falls under the service locator anti-pattern but even supposed anti-patterns have their place from time to time in a well thought out architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar situation and here's how to resolve it:

In your Service layer, create an interface called something like ISendHubMessage. Have a method called Send() that takes parameters that you're wanting to send via SignalR. Create a class within the same file called SendHubMessage that implements the interface. Have it just do a return.

In your top-level project (where your Startup.cs file is located) create another class called SendHubMessage that implements that same ISendHubMessage interface from your Service layer. Within this SendHubMessage, you can use DI to get at the hub as explained above. This method will do the actual logic of sending via SignalR.

In your Startup ConfigureServices() method, add the following line:

services.AddTransient<"Service".ISendHubMessage, "TopLevel".SendHubMessage>();

(where "Service" is the namespace to your Service-level project and "TopLevel" in the namespace to your top-level project).

What you're doing with this line is saying "Whenever an object requests the ISendHubMessage dependency from the Service layer, supply it with the SendHubMessage class defined in my top-level project".

Finally, in all the places in code outside of your top-level project that you're wanting to send messages through your hub, inject that ISendHubMessage dependency in the constructor. You can then refer to it in the class methods and when you call Send(), it will call the Send() method defined in your SendHubMessage class in your top-level project.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a little unclear, but I'm assuming you mean you want to replace the following with something that can send a message through your hub:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>{await context.Response.WriteAsync("Active");});
```

Since this is in your `Configure` method, you can simply add `IServiceCollection services` to your `Configure` methods params. Then, you can do:

```
var hub = services.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MyHub>>();
```

However, I'm not sure that this will actually do anything useful ultimately. At startup, you'd logically have no clients with subscriptions yet. As a result, sending a message through your hub at this point, would essentially go nowhere. By the time a user actually hits your site and gets connected to your hub, this part of your application has already run, and won't be hit again.

Comment: Ultimately, what I would like to do is access the hub's context from outside the hub class.   I have a method in Program.CS that handles receiving an Azure Event Hub event.  When *that* happens, I want to send a message to the UserInterfaceHub's SwitchUI (or just Clients.All.SendAsyc) - but I don't see any way to get the hub context.    GlobalHost isn't accessible and all the older ways don't work.
I tried adding what you said, but there isn't any .GetRequiredService that exposes itself in Configure/ConfigureServices, giving it IServiceCollection in the method params.  Not seeing it show up.

Comment: Essentially, I have an event delegate defined in Program/Main.   When that event is tripped, I want to send a signal-R message to all those listening to the /eventUI hub I spun up.    How do I get that hub's context so I can "talk" to it?

Comment: edited a bit to the main (see bottom).   In Main, I declare an event delegate handler.    That's a simple async method -- but from there, I want to send a message to the hub - so any client listening will get the message.   How do I connect to the hub's context so I can do that?